# Cypher: retrieve all attached nodes of more than one type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Beginner Cypher question. I know how to get all the nodes of a particular type attached to a particular person in my database. Here I am retrieving all the friends of a particular person, within 10 hops:

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..10]->(friends:Friend)
RETURN rebecca, friends
```

But how would I extend this to get nodes of two types: either the friends, or the neighbours, of Rebecca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on the label of the friends identifier :

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..10]->(other)
WHERE ALL( x IN ["Friend","Neighbour"] WHERE x IN labels(other) )
RETURN rebecca, other
```

NB: The answer from InverseFalcon is perfectly valid, here it is just another way to do this filter.

Note that this is not really ideal, `FRIEND` and `NEIGHBOUR` are semantically best described as relationships and you can see here that when 
going away from the natural way of thinking as a graph (relationships matters!) you suffer from it in your queries.

Comment: @Richard A very important point! Unless the entire graph is all from Rebecca's point of view, the :Friend and :Neighbor nodes don't provide a context as to WHOSE friends or neighbors. Relationships provide that context, and a change to your model may require simpler queries as well.

Comment: Exactly, in general except for the starting node, you wouldn't have to do any filtering other than degrees for such kind of queries, making traversals very fast and simple

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an OR we can use on the label in the MATCH itself, so you may have to filter with a WHERE clause:

```
MATCH (rebecca:Person {name:"Rebecca"})-[r*1..10]->(friendOrNeighbor)
WHERE friendOrNeighbor:Friend or friendOrNeighbor:Neighbor
RETURN DISTINCT rebecca, friendOrNeighbor
```

Keep in mind variable-length relationship matches like this are meant to find all possible paths up to the given max limit, so this is actually doing extra work that you may not need, that may be slow if there are many relationships within that local graph.

You may want to consider [apoc.path.expandConfig() from APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_with_config). If you use 'NODE_GLOBAL' for uniqueness, and specify the upper bound with `maxLevel: 10`, it's a much more efficient means of getting the nodes you want faster.